# How to enable full trust for root certificates in IOS simulator?

Tags: macbook, iphone, ios, xcode

Enable full trust for root certificates option is not displayed in iOS simulator.  How to enable full trust for root certificates in iOS simulator ?

Comment: Can you tell us what you're hoping to accomplish by changing the trust setting? This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I am doing IOS Appium Testing, so am using simulator for testing. I need to enable full trust for root certificate in IOS simulator but option is not displayed in simulator. Can you please help how to enable full trust for root certificate in IOS simulator ?

Comment: Full trust for root certificate is not displayed in iPhone simulator. I want to enable trust certificate. Can you please let me know how to enable certificate in iPhone simulator ?

Comment: Full trust of a root certificate is a bad idea for security reasons. I don't see why Appium or anything else would require it. Can you tell us what it is that you are trying to do that requires full trust of a root certificate, and why?

Comment: I want to install IPA file in iOS simulator. so I am trying to enable trust certificate. Can you please let me know how to install IPA file in iOS simulator without enable trust certificate ?

Comment: You can't install an .ipa file in the iOS Simulator. .ipa files contain only ARM code, and the Simulator runs only x86 code. When you compile an app targeting Simulator, it just generates x86 code so that Simulator doesn't have to emulate an ARM processor.